# add user ID name to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Helloo,
I want to add a firstname and user ID to the firebase database (collection user).
User ID is generated after validating the form (generated correctly - I checked), unfortunately the 'user' collection in db shows only the firstname without user ID..
It looks like the form captures the ID too early and in effect ID is null

all:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import app from './base';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const SignUp = ({ history }) => {
    const [ currentUser, setCurrentUser ] = useState(null);

    const [ firstname, setName ] = useState('');
    const [ lastname, setLastName ] = useState('');

    const handleSignUp = useCallback(
        async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
            try {
                await app
                    .auth()
                    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
                    .then(
                        await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                            if (user) {
                                setCurrentUser(user.uid);
                            }

                            console.log(currentUser);
                        })
                    )
                    .then(
                        (await firebase.database().ref('user').push()).set({ user: currentUser, firstname: firstname })
                    );

          history.push('/')
            } catch (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        },
        [currentUser, firstname, history]
    );

    const insertDetails = async () => {
        await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                setCurrentUser(user.uid);
            }
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Sign up</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSignUp}>
                <label>
                    Imie
                    <input name="firstname" value={firstname} type="text" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                </label>
                <label>
                    Nazwisko
                    <input name="lastName" value={lastname} type="text" onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)} />
                </label>
                <label>
                    Email
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                </label>
                <label>
                    Hasło
                    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </label>
                <button type="submit" onClick={insertDetails}>
                    Sign Up
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withRouter(SignUp);
```

can someone advise me on how to solve it?
thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems that I quickly see in your code:

1. You're trying to write the `currentUser` object, but setting state is an asynchronous operation.
2. You're using `push()` to generate a random key for the new user, while I'd highly recommend using the UID as the key for users.
3. You're mixing `await` with `then`, which typically is not a good idea.

So that'd end up with:

```
app.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
    .then(
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                setCurrentUser(user.uid);
                firebase.database().ref('user').child(currentUser).set({ user: currentUser, firstname: firstname })
            }
        })
    )
```